# Detect Java Method hooking in Android

Tags: android, java

Is there a way to write code to inspect Java methods' bytecodes for signs of hooking (perhaps a branch to a different function etc)?

I want to be able to inspect either system classes or my own application's classes for signs of hooking.

I looked at the ASM library (https://asm.ow2.io/) but it seems to require at least a .class file or a stream? However, in Android, class files are merged into .dex files so I am not sure how to use that library. If anyone knows of an example in using the ASM library, please let me know, thanks.